# Validar si registro fue insertado o existe C# y SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo un sp, para validar si el registro existe en la base de datos, si no existe entonces lo agrega.
Esto en la base de datos, pero en la aplicación windows forms de C#, como puedo mostrar al usuario que el registro fue insertado o si este existe, puse un MessageBox al ejecutar la inserción pero siempre se ejecuta ya que no se como validar si el registro fue realmente insertado o no.

Este es el sp:

```
    CREATE Proc AddNewAppName
(
@nameapp varchar(50)
)
AS
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM name_of_aplication WHERE name = @nameapp)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO name_of_aplication
        VALUES (@nameapp)
END
```

Y este el método en C#:

```
private void addNewAppName(string appName)
    {
        
        using (SqlConnection cnx = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString()))
        {
            //cnx.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewAppName", cnx);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nameapp", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = appName;
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record has been saved!!!!");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error conexion!!!!");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cnx.State ==ConnectionState.Open) { cnx.Close(); }
            }
        }
    }

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addNewAppName(txtNameApp.Text);
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar o asesorar, de antemano gracias.

DS

Comment: Prueba con una consulta SELECT previa, si no devuelve ningún resultado es que no está y si devuelve es que ya existe.

Comment: Te refieres a un SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE CampoTabla = @Campo
O a un COUNT?

Comment: @AntonioS.F., no pude agregarte al comentario

Comment: No lo puedo hacer con el mismo sp que ya tengo implementado?
@AntonioS.F.

Comment: Perfecto la solución que has logrado. Te has basado en que ExecuteNonQuery() retorna el número de filas afectadas y has hecho uso de eso para lograr tu propósito. Yo proponía un Select  que devolvería una fila o cero si no estaba insertado. Para todo hay varios caminos y el tuyo resulta eficaz.

Comment: Hay que contemplar la posibilidad de hacer un  `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Id` para traer el Id del elemento insertado, para ser REST compliant y devolver la url del recurso recién creado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado con un if al ejecutar el sp desde C#, aquí la solución:

```
private void addNewAppName(string appName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewAppName", cnx);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nameapp", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = appName;
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Application name already exists!","Error:",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record has been succed!!!!", "Insertion done!!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Has been getting error, try it again later.", "Connection error:",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open) { cnx.Close(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

De antemano, gracias.

DS

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que no especifica por qué no se pudo insertar. Sólo "adivinamos" basados en ese 1. Qué tal si no hay permisos de escrituras para el usuario de bd de la aplicación? Qué tal si el usuario fue borrado? Qué tal si la tabla no existe?